# CSS in ASP.NET doesn't work only for `<a>` tag

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My css wasn't working at all then I fixed it deleting cache of my browser or just `ctrl+f5` so now my css works but not for `<a>` tags I have class on them and giving that class anything won't change them not color not anything in my source css I see that changes made to the class but in element style I don't even see the class

here is my code

```html
<span id="togSpan"> <a clsss="navbarA" href="#">HOME</a><a clsss="navbarA" href="#">GENERIC</a><a clsss="navbarA" href="#">ELEMENTS</a> <i id="bars" class="fas fa-bars"></i><i id="times" class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
```

CSS

```css
 .navbarA {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
    }

    .navbarA:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #8dda06;
    }
```

Maybe it's because of `spans`?

Comment: Without code or link to your repo (if you have one), there's not much we can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written *clsss* instead of **class**. It should be:

```
<span id="togSpan">
  <a class="navbarA" href="#">HOME</a>
  <a class="navbarA" href="#">GENERIC</a>
  <a class="navbarA" href="#">ELEMENTS</a>
  <i id="bars" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  <i id="times" class="fas fa-times"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked!!! I didn't notice :/